# C# GUI Freezes When Updating Labels Via Timer

Tags: c#, user-interface, timer, visual-studio-2013, freeze

I have a very simple C# program (.net 4.5, VS 2013) that is running using Winforms to grab the current CPU Speed and Max CPU Speed and update the following labels:
[lblCPUMaxValue and lblCPUCurrentValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q61vH.png)

```
lblCPUMaxValue
lblCPUCurrentValue
```

I created a timer called timerCPUstats that ticks every 3000ms and calls the function updatePerfInfo():

```
public uint CPUSpeed()
{
    ManagementObject Mo = new ManagementObject("Win32_Processor.DeviceID='CPU0'");
    uint speed = (uint)(Mo["CurrentClockSpeed"]);
    Mo.Dispose();
    return speed;
}

public uint maxCPUSpeed()
{
    ManagementObject Mo = new ManagementObject("Win32_Processor.DeviceID='CPU0'");
    uint speed = (uint)(Mo["MaxClockSpeed"]);
    Mo.Dispose();
    return speed;
} 

public string formatMhzGhz(uint mhz)
{
    decimal ghz = (decimal)mhz / 1000;
    ghz = Math.Round(ghz, 2);
    string stringGhz = ghz.ToString() + " GHz";
    return stringGhz;
}

public void updatePerfInfo()
{
    lblCPUMaxValue.Text = formatMhzGhz(maxCPUSpeed());
    lblCPUCurrentValue.Text = formatMhzGhz(CPUSpeed());
}
```

The problem is that every time the labels update the program freezes for a few seconds. It basically become non interactive / frozen. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Are you running on WinForms? WPF?   Your UI is freezing because the same thread that is updating the UI is also running calculations.  Spinning up a backgroundworker to handle this would be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're blocking the UI thread by performing long running non-UI work in the UI thread.  You need to offload that work to another thread and then update the UI with the results of that work.

A `BackgroundWorker` is specifically designed for this exact operation.  Compute the `Result` in the `DoWork` event handler and set that result, then display the `Result` to the UI using the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.

The other option, if you're using C# 5.0, is to use `await`, which would let you write:

```
public async void updatePerfInfo()
{
    lblCPUMaxValue.Text = await Task.Run(()=>formatMhzGhz(maxCPUSpeed()));
    lblCPUCurrentValue.Text = await Task.Run(()=>formatMhzGhz(CPUSpeed()));
}
```

Comment: I am using C# 5.0, so that await was perfect. I tried backgroundworker  and got lost but I'll probably figure that out anyway. Thanks!